# How to use material ui sx props with a styles object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a styles object that would look like this:

```js
styles = {
  color: "#333",
  fontSize: "16px",
};
```

I could apply styles to a Material UI component like below and it would work.

```html
<Button sx={styles}>Example</Button>;
```

However, what if the `Button` component already had custom styles? How would I push my styles object then? For example, in this case:

```html
<Button
  sx={{
    backgroundColor: "red",
    fontWeight: "700",
  }}
>
  Example
</Button>;
```

How would I add the styles object without overwriting the `sx` prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Spread syntax, like below. If you wanna know more about it, you can read on MDN's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

> What it's doing, in my words, is that it removes styles object's {}, and add it into the final object.

```js
styles = {
  color: "#333",
  fontSize: "16px",
};
```

```html
<Button
  sx={{
    backgroundColor: "red",
    fontWeight: "700",
    ...styles,
  }}
>
  Example
</Button>
```